# How can I remap the command ":u" (UNDO) in Vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to remap the command `:u` with `CTRL+z`?

Comment: With all due respect, learn Vim and get used to it. Don't try to change Vim into what you're used to. Once you have mastered the basics you can look to customize its behavior - right now you're just trying to stay in your comfort zone. To be effective with Vim you have to get out of your comfort zone and learn what makes it powerful.

Comment: You're right, it would be "morally" correct to do this.
The problem is that right now I don't have time to learn Vim well and therefore I am looking for shortcuts that would save me time.

Comment: Are you forced to use Vim? There are likely alternatives available that you are more used to, e.g. `nano`. P.S.: I didn't downvote your question.

Comment: I am following a course in C, in particular "Networks" where my professor makes us use Vim so I do not currently have the objective of learning the editor but rather how a connection between Client and Server works.

PS: I'm glad because I don't like downvotes for no reason.

Comment: That is a strange conclusion. If your professor forces you to use something it's safe to assume they want you to learn it.

Comment: No, he is not forcing us, perhaps I expressed myself badly.
We can safely use `nano` or whatever other editors we want but the point is, during the lessons, when he's coding in front of us, it would be better if we use `Vim`, AS HE DOES, for better comprehension. Again, certainly he would be proud if the students learned his own favorite editor, but precisely, it **is not his primary goal**. I don't know if I explained myself.

Comment: @AlbertoUrsino You could still see this as an *opportunity* to learn Vim enough to be somewhat proficient with it... I know you're probably already overwhelmed, but if you could carve 60 to 90 minutes to spend learning some basics of Vim, it should be enough to get you going. The thing is, you don't know whether this will be useful to you in the future, but if it happens to be, having the basics will help you ramp up quickly. I suggest you start with `vimtutor`. Asking questions here (or on [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com)) should help you too. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`u` is already a normal-mode command to undo the last change. You can remap Control-Z to `undo` with

```
nnoremap <C-z> u
```

(assuming, of course, that Control-z isn't already being used by your terminal as to send SIGSTOP to the foreground process).